# I am trying to delete data from database, but sometime data is deleted and sometime data is not deleted

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am trying to delete data on didSelectRowAtIndexPath method of table view from a database but data is not deleted. sometimes records are deleted, but sometimes not deleted. 
displaying old data.

```
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, & contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *deleteSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"delete from userDetails where name = '%@'", _name.text];
        NSLog(@"%@:", deleteSQL);
        const char *delete_stmt = [deleteSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2( contactDB, delete_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            _dbStatus.text = @"record is deleted";
        } else {
            _dbStatus.text = @"record not deleted";
            NSLog(@"Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));
        }
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }
    [tableview reloadData];
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [resultentArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *selectedRow1 = [[resultentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"name"];
}
```

Comment: Probably unrelated to your issue but never build a query using `stringWithFormat`. Properly bind values into the prepared statement. You should also call `sqlite3_finalize` on all prepared statements after you are done with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show how you call the method for deleting from the database, or where `_name.text` is coming from, but my initial inclination is that you're deleting the target row from your data model array prior to using it:

```
[resultentArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *selectedRow1 = [[resultentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"name"];
```

which would result in selectedRow1 being the object at the *next* index after your target row.  If you were attempt to delete the last row, I would assume this would cause in index out of bounds error.

Try reversing the order of those two (fetch the target row then delete it) and see if it makes any difference.  If it doesn't edit your question to post some additional code as to how you're calling the method to delete from your database, and how `_name.text` is getting set.

```
NSString *selectedRow1 = [[resultentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"name"];
[resultentArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: yes, when i am delete targated row with record from db, that time giving  index out of bounds error.

Comment: till now, can't deleting data from database using above code.